# Width of a div increases in some cases even though I have overflow:auto

Tags: css, reactjs

I was trying to create a table like grid with two columns (50/50 width), such that inside each column, each row consist of further two columns (50/50 width), here is [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gncfmd). Also my goal was to say if right column inside a row takes more width a scroll bar to appear.

It seems to work in most cases. For example it works with such data:

```
  // Array with two sub arrays, each sub array holds rows for that column.
  let items = [
    [{ value: "2", label: "1" }], 
    [
      {
        label: "test ",
        value: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
      }
      // {
      //   label: "test",
      //   value:
      //     "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ut nisi feugiat arcu elementum feugiat. Sed varius eros ac convallis interdum. Quisque tincidunt mauris vitae ipsum malesuada tempus. Cras ut dui vitae tortor finibus rhoncus ut in enim. Morbi nec nibh vitae mauris pretium convallis. Curabitur sed ornare arcu. Fusce dictum, lacus eget efficitur posuere"
      // }
    ]
  ];
```

i.e., the blue rectangles correctly divide screen in two, also the right most column has a scrollbar. See [here](https://ibb.co/m0WCRYF).

But if I uncomment the item from above code snippet (the one with larger text), the right blue rectangle takes too much width. Why is this happening? Why is there different behavior depending on which item I uncomment?

Comment: its happening because of the css `white-space:nowrap` if you the container full width you can add width to the cell and try might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try maxWidth: "50%" like this:

```html
<div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      {items.map((x, i) => {
        return (
          <div style={{ flex: 1, maxWidth: "50%" }} key={i}>
            {x.map((y, j) => {
              return (
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    border: "1px solid blue"
                  }}
                  key={j}
                >
                  <div style={{ flex: 1, maxWidth: "50%" }}>{y.label}:</div>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      flex: 1,
                      whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                      overflow: "auto"
                    }}
                  >
                    {y.value}
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue was somewhere in css, and the fact that you over-complicated a simple task with a bunch of unnecessary loops and css which makes it messier and thus harder to figure out the issue, I wrote some code to show the way I would achieve this, which is much cleaner. Hope you can learn something from it :)

```
// App.js
let items = [
    [{ value: "2", label: "1" }],
    [
        // {
        //  label: "test ",
        //  value: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        // }
        {
            label: "test",
            value:
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ut nisi feugiat arcu elementum feugiat. Sed varius eros ac convallis interdum. Quisque tincidunt mauris vitae ipsum malesuada tempus. Cras ut dui vitae tortor finibus rhoncus ut in enim. Morbi nec nibh vitae mauris pretium convallis. Curabitur sed ornare arcu. Fusce dictum, lacus eget efficitur posuere"
        }
    ]
];
return (
    <>
        <div className="row">
            {items.map((item, i) => (
                <div className="col-6" key={i}>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-6">{item[0].label}</div>
                        <div className="col-6 scroller">{item[0].value}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    </>
);
```

```
// style.css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col-6 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.scroller {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```